# No State shown in React DevTools Profiler

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

For some reason I cannot see the state of the component for a particular commit.
Am I missing something really obvious or is this feature somehow not supported?

I am using Firefox 72.0.1.

In the image below I double-clicked Table (one click doesn't help either).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such feature, you can't see component's state on particular commit.

You can achieve it by logging the state on component's render.

Note that there is a familiar feature in [`redux-devtools`](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-devtools).

Comment: I saw this functionality in the React's tutorial:

https://reactjs.org/see-all-commits-for-a-fiber-99cb4321ded8eb0c21ae5fc673878563.gif

Here can be seen the state for a particular component for a commit.

Plus, in the right corner there is a Component Chart view, which, the same, is missing for me.

Comment: It's not a commit's state, its what you can see in the `Component` tab next to `Profiler`.

Comment: In the videos on https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/09/10/introducing-the-react-profiler.html#flame-chart they do show state in the Profiler tab.  Maybe this was removed since 2018 when that blog post was published.

Comment: As mentioned in a similar question, this feature was removed for performance reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61120759/why-react-dev-tools-profiler-dont-show-me-component-props