# Why react dev tools Profiler dont show me component props?

Tags: reactjs, profiler, react-devtools

I start to learn optimization of React. And see some learning resources, and on them, I can see component props in the Profiler. But in my Profiler, I don't see any props. Why?

And how can I see a current render component props in Profiler?

A make screenshots to show this:
[image]

Comment: Did you manage to get it done or view the props with other workarounds?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The Legacy DevTools extension added a significant performance overhead and would be become unusable in large apps. [The new DevTools improved](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/CHANGELOG.md#400-august-15-2019) by minimizing communication between the front end(the extension you see: Component, Profiler) and back end, which render component information only when needed.

The Props changed in the Profiler is still there, however it's not as detailed. It lacks [displaying names of custom Hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-devtools/OVERVIEW.md#inspecting-hooks). It does show prop names but only the ones that changed and doesn't show their values. 
[image]

The Changelog unfortunately doesn't explicitly list that it dropped support to display prop values and should've been more clear on that.